# Track test coverage history(trend)

Tags: java, junit4, clover, test-coverage

**Goal** - track unit/functional/integration tests coverage history on some regular basis (weekly, every release, etc) for relatively long period (6 months).
JUnit plugin in Jenkins out of the box does that per every build and problem here that it does not allow track specific slices (milestones, releases, etc) and history is kept for some fixed number of builds. So, here we are dependent on Jenkins workspace folder content which is not reliable. 
 
Currently, we are capturing metrics from Jenkins and manually moving them into a table in confluence, so that we can use raw data to build graphs, trends. As you understand this approach requires a lot of manual effort and does not scale for cases when we need to track different test types, multiple projects 
Is there any existing tool that provide capability to track history and show the trend?

Comment: Have you looked at jenkins extension points? You'd would only need to persist the data you want

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian Clover can track historical coverage, however, keep in mind that you will still have to gather history point files in some place:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/'Historical'+Report
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-historypoint